# How to change views pager with View All links

Tags: views, paging

I am using the full pager in views module. I am displaying 40 items per page. The full pager display links like this

1 2 3 4 5 next last
I want to change it to this

View All 1 2 3 4

How will I do this? Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of you achieving such a thing would be to create another display page in addition to the display page which already has a pager. And using html/CSS add a link to the footer of the views with pager called View all linking to the display page you created that shows all content.

Comment: Don't you need next and last buttons... You just want 1 2 3 4....??
theme_pager() is used to alter pager functions in general